# urldecode in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I transform

```
www.bestbuy.com/site/Electronics\Audio\abcat0200000.c=3fid=3dabcat0200000
```

into its original format?

```
www.bestbuy.com/site/Electronics/Audio/abcat0200000.c?id=abcat0200000
```

Is there a `urldecode`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well the thing with `=3f` and `=3d` is quoted-printable encoding. Ruby can decode it with the `.unpack("M")` method.

The backslashes? They're just weird and wrong. It would probably be safe to string-replace them to `/` since backslash should not be in a URL to begin with.

Answer (score 185):

A better method is [`CGI.unescape`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-unescape):
*URI.unescape is deprecated*

```
decoded_uri = CGI.unescape(encoded_uri)
```

Comment: Why not use `CGI.unescape` instead?

Comment: From the latest Ruby docs for [`URI.unescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html):

"This method is obsolete and should not be used. Instead, use [CGI.unescape](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-unescape), [URI.decode_www_form](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form) or [URI.decode_www_form_component](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form_component) depending on your specific use case."

Answer (score 38):

Via `decode`:

```
require 'uri'
URI.decode(encoded_uri)
```

Ruby `2.7` and above:

```
require 'uri'
URI.decode_www_form_component(encoded_uri)
```

Comment: this method is also deprecated according to [RuboCop](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/UriEscapeUnescape),  [take](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2946687/take)'s comment applies here as well: `URI.decode_www_form` or `URI.decode_www_form_component` should be used instead.

Answer (score 23):

The equivalent of PHP's `urldecode` in Ruby is `CGI::unescape`.